# Multiple day on day changes based on dates in data as not continuous

Tags: sql

See table A. There are number of sales per date. The dates are not continuous. 
I want table B where it gives the sales moves per the previous date in the dataset.

I am trying to do it in SQL but get stuck. I can do an individual day on day difference by entering the date but I want one where I don't need to enter the dates manually

A

```
Date         Sales
01/01/2019      100
05/01/2019      200
12/01/2019      50
25/01/2019      25
31/01/2019      200
```

B

```
Date            DOD Move
01/01/2019      -
05/01/2019      +100
12/01/2019      -150
25/01/2019      -25
31/01/2019      +175
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       (sales - lag(sales) over (order by date)) as dod_move
from t;
```